# CMS for tire shop

Tags: open-source, content-management-system, e-commerce

I would like to get you opinions, what open source CMS is best for online tire shop? Basically I need it to have advanced search options, so I could make search by tire height, width, rim size, season type ect. I was thinking about OpenCart, but It seems it has very limited search capabilities. Any suggestions?

Comment: create your own. There are number of frameworks that can handle some primary needs for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it that Magento is the best way to go. Many extensions, fantastic community, good documentation.